# 404 on remove AMP content using update-ping GET request

Tags: amp-html

I am trying this morning to make a `update-ping` request to Google, but it returns 404

https://www-cbc-ca.cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/c/www.cbc.ca/amp/1.3963531

This used to work before today, is Google implementing a new way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google contact me saying

"I would like to confirm that the update-ping is working as intended now."

Thanks Google

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [blog](https://getmxt.com/update-google-amp-cache), be noted that *removal of content from the Google AMP Cache will not immediately cease traffic flowing to removed content, which may result in user-facing errors such as 404 or 500*.

> Well, it turns out that once your AMP pages are in the index, Google seems reticent to let go of them.
>
> The documentation says clearly that even if you update ping remove them, they still take some time to disappear.
>
> And even once that happens, the AMP error page links to the old, now-invalid /amp URL, returning a 404.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but that does not help. According to Google documentation in https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping in the section "update-ping request", they say clearly in a note:  


`Note: The update-ping request always returns a 204 status (no content).`   


and it was working until Friday Aug 11, 2017.

Comment: Google: "I would like to confirm that the update-ping is working as intended now."